How do you pass options to doctest when running 'make doctest' from Sphinx?
We use make html to build HTML docs from .rst docs and our Python code using Sphinx. We have also enabled the sphinx.ext.doctest extension in Sphinx so that we can test any code samples in our docs by running make doctest. If you do this:
python -m doctest -h

you'll see doctest has many flags, e.g., -f to fail fast rather than run all the tests; and the ability to test only named files rather than all of them. But how can I pass these flags to doctest when running make doctest? Whilst debugging new code samples I'd really like doctest to only examine the one file I'm debugging, and to fail as soon as it encounters the first error. However, doing things like this, for example:
make doctest SPHINXOPTS="-f"

doesn't work; doctest still reports multiple errors rather than the first one it finds.

The Sphinx extension does not support such command line options, only the Python module does. You could use directives in your .rst files to configure groups of tests.

I haven't found a way to do this via make doctest but this will run doctest against only a single rst file if you run it from the directory where your conf.py file is located: sphinx-build -b doctest . _build/doctest <relative_path_to_your_rst_file>
